# How to merge db rows together?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a query below which displays these results:

```
SELECT q.QuestionId, q.QuestionContent, an.Answer
FROM Answer an
INNER JOIN Question q ON q.AnswerId = an.AnswerId;
```

Result of query:

```
QuestionId     QuestionContent           Answer
1              Who are me and you         B
1              Who are me and you         D
2              Name these Cars            A
2              Name these Cars            B
2              Name these Cars            E
3              What is 2+2                B
```

What I want to do is merge the answers together for the same QuestionId so the result looks like this below:

```
QuestionId     QuestionContent           Answer
1              Who are me and you         B D
2              Name these Cars            A B E
3              What is 2+2                B
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
SELECT q.QuestionId,
       q.QuestionContent,
       GROUP_CONCAT(an.Answer, SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM Answer an
INNER JOIN Question q ON q.AnswerId = an.AnswerId
GROUP BY q.QuestionId,
       q.QuestionContent
```